# Google Sheets API Image Formula

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, gspread

I'm currently trying to use Google Sheets API to insert pictures on python. However, whenever it posts to sheet. It adds a ' to the beginning of the formula. Is there any way to remove that apostrophe. This is an example of how I'm inserting it into the google sheet:

```
    picture = [f'=IMAGE("{url}",4,100,100)']
    sheet.insert_row(picture,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put `=IMAGE("{url}",4,100,100)` to the 1st row in `sheet`.
- You want to achieve this using gspread with python.

  - From `sheet.insert_row(picture,1)` in your question, I thought like this.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

At gspread, it seems that `RAW` is used for the ValueInputOption as the default value. By this, `=IMAGE("{url}",4,100,100)` is put as the string. In order to put it as the formula, please use `USER_ENTERED` for the ValueInputOption. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
sheet.insert_row(picture,1)
```

#### To:

```
sheet.insert_row(picture, 1, 'USER_ENTERED')
```

or

```
sheet.insert_row(picture, 1, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

#### References:

- [insert_row(values, index=1, value_input_option='RAW')](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.insert_row)
- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Wonderful! This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much

Comment: @ThatBoyCap Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.